# Why doesn't GLib use 'const' in these functions?

Tags: c, constants, glib

I have a simple question about GLib.

I have the following code:

```
static const char *words[] = { "one", "two", "three", NULL };

void main() {
  puts(g_strjoinv("+", words));
}
```

This code prints `one+two+three`. It uses a GLib function which joins strings.

The [signature](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/docs/latest/glib/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-strjoinv) of that function is:

```
char *g_strjoinv (const char *separator, char **str_array);
```

(To be exact, GLib uses `gchar`, not `char`, but let's ignore this.)

Now, I wonder why the parameter is `char **str_array` and not `const char **str_array`. It forces me to do an explicit cast to get rid of the compiler's warning ("expected 'char **' but argument is of type 'const char **'"):

```
  puts(g_strjoinv("+", (char **)words));
```

I look in [GLib's reference](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/docs/latest/glib/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html) and I see that **all** the functions there are defined this way: they accept `char **`, not `const char **`.

Why is that? Why doesn't GLib use `const char **`?

The need to use an explicit cast to get rid of the const makes my code less safe (because the compiler no longer checks the arguments' compatibility). It also makes me nervous because GLib doesn't "sign a contract" that say it won't change my data.

Comment: Great question, str_array surely isn't changed(?), in that case const would make sense.

Comment: @self: Yep, and it's not a problem with just this one function. It's in *all* of GLib's functions that accept an array of strings. I guess they have a good reason for doing this and I want to know what it is.

Comment: You may want to look at [this question](http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html). If you had a regular `char **` which is entirely possible, you wouldn't be able to pass it to a function expecting `const char **` without a cast, either, so you wouldn't be solving a problem by declaring it as such.

Comment: Those pesky stars. @PaulGriffiths Your should make that an answer.

Comment: `void main()` should be `int main(void)`. If you got `void main()` from a book, get a better one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The assumption in your question is that if the second argument of `g_strjoinv()` was declared as type `const char **`, then you can just as easily pass either a `const char **` or a `char **` to it.

Unfortunately, this isn't true. As explained in [this question from the comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html), using a pointer to `T` (for any type `T`) where a pointer to `const T` is expected is OK, but only where the mismatch is at the top level of indirection. That is to say, you can pass a `char *` where a `const char *` is expected, but you cannot (without a cast) pass a `char **` where a `const char **` is expected, because in this case the mismatch is at the second level of indirection. The linked question explains in some detail *why* it works this way, which is "somewhat obscure".

So the upshot is there there is no type (in C) which will accept both a `char **` and a `const char **` without at least one of them requiring a cast. This being the case, there's probably not much reason to prefer either other than convenience, and the library authors apparently decided to go with the former. As a matter of pure speculation, I'd guess that wanting to pass a `char **` is slightly more common than wanting to pass a `const char **`, and so the option they picked is probably more convenient.

In your case, you can just drop the `const` qualifier from the definition of your array. It might seem like bad form, if you like `const`, but since you have an array of pointers which point to string literals, your program is overwhelmingly likely to loudly complain and fail if anything attempts to write to them anyway, so you're not really losing safety in any meaningful way in this particular case. Even though it's undefined behavior to attempt to modify them, string literals have type array of `char` in C, not array of `const char` (unlike C++).

Slightly more obscure, but even if you could pass it as a `const char **`, the function here could still modify the pointers even if it couldn't modify what they point to, and just cause mayhem in a different way, so the promise the function made still wouldn't be guaranteeing that what you pass to the function wouldn't be changed in some way.

Comment: That's an **excellent** answer, thank you very much! I had encountered this issue before but I didn't know it was related to this present case as well. Now, thanks to you, I understand it fully. BTW, you say that I can just drop my "const", but when I do this GCC warns me ("initialization discards 'const' ..."), becuase, I guess, it sees string literals as constants.

Comment: (BTW, thanks for the last paragraph too. My C skills are a bit rusty and I needed this correction.)

Comment: That sounds like a spurious warning, are you sure you're not compiling this as C++, or with some extension set? Compiling as standard C should not give you that warning.

Comment: You're right. I found out that gcc is invoked with "-Wwrite-strings". It seems that autoconf is responsible for this. I'll now try, out of curiosity, to find out what in my 'configure.ac' causes this.